# For BlackBerry, how can my java program select a specific menu item in another BlackBerry program?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I simulate a menu item selection for an exact menu item like for example, "New Note" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new memo then simply use the [Invoke](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html#APP_TYPE_MEMOPAD) class and supply it with a [MemoArguments](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/MemoArguments.html#MemoArguments%28%29) object.  Note that you can do this for other core BB applications beyond the memo application.

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MEMOPAD, new MemoArguments(MemoArguments.ARG_NEW));
```

If you want to actually click on a menu item in another application then you could try using the [EventInjector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventInjector.html) class, although I don't know how well that will work for you.  If it's a third party application that you want to control you probably won't have a lot of success.

Comment: I was using "New Note" as an example menu item. The menu item could be "New Widget" "Play" "Close" etc. What I need to do is select an exact menu item from the menu in BlackBerry. If you inject say the the letter "N" it will go to the first Menu item starting with "N". But if you are playing  music, the "Now Playing" menu item appears which makes it chose that. So I'm wondering if anyone knows how to select the exact menu item in a BlackBeryy menu.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there's any way to do that.  If you're trying to control a separate application that you wrote then you could have that application implement GlobalEventListener and send notifications telling it what to do.  If you're trying to control a third party application that you didn't write then I think you're out of luck.  I'd love to be proven wrong however.